# How can I freeze an erc20 token in another holder's wallet

Tags: tokens, erc-20

Token was compromised and some portions went to a wrong hand, now owners of token wants to freeze that wallet holding it, is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an ERC20 **compliant** token, then you cannot freeze the holdings of another token holder.
To be able to freeze the holdings of another token holder, then you would have to implement custom freezing/pausing functionality to the token before deploying to the main net.

Comment: Let me send you the testnet of this token as it has that freezing function to see if it can be solved

Comment: I have to post the code of the token so maybe you can help me check on testnet the possibility of such contract and relate back to me: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=57553255385193638969

Comment: sure but send me the testnet, I'm not going to download any files.

Comment: here; https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x77a4e3533a5c1449d180752a4186846373f5214e#code

Comment: Nothing you can do to target the wallet specifically, you can only pause the transferable state of the entire supply.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. That means that if the token is paused, nobody holding any token can transfer from any wallet to another right?

Comment: that's correct.

Comment: if the token is listed on centralized exchange, would it affect the people trading it?

Comment: it would effect everyone with any token holdings.